# Wallpaper resizing and zooming in my Wordpress Landing Page in theme

Tags: css, wordpress, background, themes

Disclaimer: I am a non-programming newbie who has no idea of CSS and HTML. So please make the suggestions it easy for me.

I am using the Ohio theme for my Wordpress website.

I am using their landing page (ohio.clbthemes.com) and trying to edit it.

I am facing a problem in the first section. I have used a 1920x1080 wallpaper for the background of the first row.

The background zooms in in the mobile version and resizes when loading (also in the desktop). Why is this happening?

Also the default background of this page is pink, which also pops up first when loading the site. Then all rows and other background comes on.

I want to remove this background and change it. Where do I do it?

Comment: Please put code of image's HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Where do find the image's HTML and CSS code? Where do I add it in the row so that it appears as it is?

Comment: Sorry I pronounced it wrong. Can you please put HTML and CSS code where your picture is (only that part - header/main/footer...).

Comment: I dont know how to put HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Please refer to [this page](https://wpbuffs.com/edit-source-code-in-wordpress/)

Comment: What do I need to do to solve the problem?

Comment: We need code for [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please tell me the steps